# Is it possbile to format a date without a conversion to UTC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, utc

I would like to format a date/time maintaining the original date/time.

My problem is that if I use this jquery code:

```
var time = $.formatDateTime('M d hh:ii', new Date(2013-12-13T14:00:00Z));
```

The result is `Dec 13 15:00 UTC`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are using this plugin, right? https://github.com/agschwender/jquery.formatDateTime

Answer (score 1):

The `Z` on your time string explicitly says the date/time is in UTC. (But the odd thing about JavaScript's take on this is that even though that looks like an ISO-8601 string, if the `Z` weren't there, it would *still* be UTC whereas ISO-8601 says it should be local time.)

Oddly, there's no string-based mechanism in JavaScript that's **in the spec** for parsing a specified date/time string format in local time. Two approaches for you, one is per the specification, the other is not but I've never seen a browser that didn't do it:

1. Parse the string yourself. This is using the specified `new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)` constructor:

   ```
   var str = "2013-12-13T14:00:00Z";
   var parts = str.replace(/Z$/, '').split(/[-T:]/);
   var dt = new Date(
       parseInt(parts[0], 10),     // Year
       parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1, // Month (0 = Jan)
       parseInt(parts[2], 10),     // Day
       parseInt(parts[3], 10),     // Hour
       parseInt(parts[4], 10),     // Minute
       parseInt(parts[5], 10)      // Second
   );
   var time = $.formatDateTime('M d hh:ii', dt);
   ```
2. Rely on unspecified, but very common, behavior: However, every browser I've ever seen will parse `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss` (with **slashes**, not `-`) as local time.

   So:

   ```
   var str = "2013-12-13T14:00:00Z";
   str = str.replace(/-/g, '/').replace(/Z$/, '').replace(/T/, ' ');
   var time = $.formatDateTime('M d hh:ii', new Date(str));
   ```

   Again, that's not specified behavior, but I've never seen a browser that didn't do it.